# What is the time complexity of these two nested for loops?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I found that time complexity of this code is O(N<sup>2</sup>). Is it right?

```
for(i=n;i>=1;i--) {
  for(j=n-i; j>=1; j--) {
    x++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The outer loop will be executed `n` times. The inner loop, on the average, will be executed `n/2` times. Multiply the complexity of the inner loop and the outer loop to get `O(n * n / 2)`, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: how second loop will execute n/2 times? it will executes n-1 times. isn't it? if so then explain please.

Comment: The first time the outer loop is entered `i` is equal `n`, so the inner loop is not executed at all. The next time `i` is equal to `n-1`, so `x++` is executed 1 time. Then 2 times, 3, 4 and so on until `i = 1`, then it's executed `n-1` times. The average of the numbers is 1, 2 ... , n-1 is on the order of O(n/2).

Comment: Another way of looking is that summation of 1, 2, ... n - 1 has an n squared term so order is O(n^2)